# Android SharedPreferences IOException Error

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So I'm trying to write some strings to `SharedPreferences` in my android app. I first declare SharedPreferences and its original properties in my `Application` subclass. I want to be able to change the values of my data in other activities in the app but I get the error below. How should I fix this? Some other guy posted the same question but no one really answered him so that's why I'm asking again. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

```
SharedPreferencesImpl﹕ writeToFile: Got exception:
java.io.IOException: java.nio.charset.CoderResult[Malformed-input error with erroneous input length 1]
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flush(FastXmlSerializer.java:225)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.append(FastXmlSerializer.java:86)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.escapeAndAppendString(FastXmlSerializer.java:127)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.text(FastXmlSerializer.java:361)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeValueXml(XmlUtils.java:425)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:185)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:596)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Some example code:
This is declared in my `Application` class:

```
editor.putString("firstRun", "true");
editor.apply();
```

This is declared in my outside activity:

```
editor.putString("firstRun", "false");
editor.apply();
```

And this is how my shared preferences is declared (in my `Application` subclass):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("My App", 0);
```

EDIT: 
Here's more code:
Application Class

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    public static SharedPreferences prefs;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Data Configurations etc
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("My App", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
        Map<String, ?> keys = prefs.getAll();
        if (keys.size() == 0) {
            editor.putString("firstRun", "true");
            editor.apply();
        }

        // Block of Code saving more strings to shared preferences
    }
}
```

Activity where preferences are being changed:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MainApplication.prefs.edit();
        if (MainApplication.prefs.getString("firstRun", "false").equals("true")) {
            // Set data correctly
            editor.remove("firstRun");
            editor.putString("firstRun", "false");
            editor.apply();

            // yadda yadda yadda more code doing other things not related to shared preferences
           }
       }
    }
}
```

SHOULD'VE MENTIONED THIS, I am also saving json stuff to the shared preferences.

Some logcats of the `SharedPreferences`:

```
Tutorial, true
Notification0, {"alert":"Test Alert","category":"news","date":"Aug 7, 2015","name":"Alert01"}
VersionNum, 1.0
firstRun, false
New0, {"alert":"Test Alert","category":"news","fileData":"<!doctype html><html itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.org/WebPage\" lang=\"en\"><head><meta content=\"Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for.\" name=\"description\"><meta content=\"noodp\" name=\"robots\"><meta content=\"/images/google_favicon_128.png\" itemprop=\"image\"><meta content=\"origin\" id=\"mref\" name=\"referrer\"><title>Google</title>   <script>(function(){window.google={kEI:'29q4Va--H4W0eI2jsMgP',kEXPI:'3700337,3700372,4028875,4029815,4031109,4032235,4032500,4032678,4033307,4033344,4034882,4035869,4036527,4036848,4037333,4037457,4037569,4038012,4038399,4038464,4038821,4039386,4039462,4039879,4039886,4039895,4039937,4040028,4040061,4040112,4040136,4040412,4040513,4040678,4040849,4040865,4040976,4040982,4041079,4041304,4041323,4041440,4042052,4042103,4042125,8300095,8300200,8300203,8500394,8501295,8501407,8501489,8501584,8501767,10200083,10200095,10201249,10201251,16200005,16200009,16200011',authuser:0,j:{en:1,bv:21,pm:'p',u:'c9c918f0',qbp:0,rre:false},kscs:'c9c918f0_21'};google.kHL='en';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute(\"eid\")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute(\"leid\")));)a=a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return\"https:\"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){return null};google.time=function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,d,e,g){a=google.logUrl(a,b,d,e,g);if(\"\"!=a){b=new Image;var c=google.lc,f=google.li;c[f]=b;b.onerror=b.onload=b.onabort=function(){delete c[f]};window.google&&window.google.vel&&window.google.vel.lu&&window.google.vel.lu(a);b.src=a;google.li=f+1}};google.logUrl=function(a,b,d,e,g){var c=\"\",f=google.ls||\"\";if(!d&&-1==b.search(\"&ei=\")){var h=google.getEI(e),c=\"&ei=\"+h;-1==b.search(\"&lei=\")&&((e=google.getLEI(e))?c+=\"&lei=\"+e:h!=google.kEI&&(c+=\"&lei=\"+google.kEI))}a=d||\"/\"+(g||\"gen_204\")+\"?atyp=i&ct=\"+a+\"&cad=\"+b+c+f+\"&zx=\"+google.time();/^http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()&&(google.ml(Error(\"a\"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a=\"\");return a};google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];return!1};google.load=function(a,b,d){google.x({id:a+k++},function(){google.load(a,b,d)})};var k=0;})();google.kCSI={};\ngoogle.j.b=(!!location.hash&&!!location.hash.match('[#&]((q|fp)=|tbs=rimg|tbs=simg|tbs=sbi)'))\n||(google.j.qbp==1);(function(){window.google.sn='webhp';google.timers={};google.startTick=function(a,b){google.timers[a]={t:{start:google.time()},it:{},bfr:!!b,b:{},olh:null};window.performance&&window.performance.now&&(google.timers[a].wsrt=Math.floor(window.performance.now()))};google.tick=function(a,b,d){google.timers[a]||google.startTick(a);google.timers[a].t[b]=d||google.time()};google.bit=function(a,b,d){google.timers[a]||google.startTick(a);var c=google.timers[a].it[b];c||(c=google.timers[a].it[b]=[]);var e=c.push({s:d||google.time()})-1;return function(){c[e]&&(c[e].e=d||google.time())}};google.blockCSI=function(a,b){google.timers[a].b[b]=!0};google.unblockCSI=function(a,b,d){if(a=google.timers[a]){a=a.b;a[b]=!1;for(var c in a)if(a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&a[c])return;google.csiReport&&google.csiReport(void 0,void 0,d)}};google.rolh=function(a){google.uolh();google.timers.load&&(google.timers.load.olh=a,window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener(\"load\",a,!1):window.attachEvent&&window.attachEvent(\"onload\",a))};google.uolh=function(){if(google.timers.load){var a=google.timers.load;a.olh&&(window.addEventListener?window.removeEventListener(\"load\",a.olh,void 0):window.attachEvent&&window.detachEvent(\"onload\",a.olh),a.olh=null)}};google.startTick(\"load\",!0);google.blockCSI(\"load\",\"ol\");google.blockCSI(\"load\",\"xjs\");google.iml=function(a,b){google.tick(\"iml\",a.id||a.src||a.name,b)};})();google.afte=!0;google.aft=functio
```

The odd thing is that when I set Tutorial to false later on in my app, it does set it to false. But then when I rerun the program, Tutorial is set back to true. However, I don't reset it in my code anywhere. This sometimes happens with firstRun as well but sometimes it DOES get set to false... Any ideas? I'll double check.

Comment: Can you show some more context in your code? Like where you declare, initialise, use  shared pref and editor objects.

Comment: @ci_ just added more code

Comment: @Ryan Can you show us the json stuff you are putting in the `SharedPreferences`? There seems to be a dodgy character in there.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I will but I'm getting the above error when I'm trying to rewrite the firstRun String... so I'm suspecting it's not just the json stuff. unless it really is?

Comment: After `keys = prefs.getAll();` can you do `Log.d("MyClass", keys.toString());` and tell us the result? I'm trying to reproduce this error but I can't.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Just posted the edits

Comment: @Ryan I'm afraid I still can't reproduce this. I could be wrong, but I think android internally saves a `SharedPreferences` object as xml, so it's possible you could confuse the parser by storing strings that contain certain characters. `SharedPreferences` are meant for small amounts of data anyway, so my advice would be to save those complex objects as files in internal storage.

Comment: Your `fileData` property in your JSON contains an XML document. I'd throw this whole thing through `Commons-lang 3.4`'s `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml` call, then call the unescape when retrieving.

Comment: @PaulBoddington hm alright I will look up ways to save to internal storage thanks!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce really? I didn't know that. Will look up at that call as well

Comment: Well technically it's `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(String)`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I switched my json files to internal storage and now my variables are saving. Thanks! If you want to write it as answer I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason for your problem, but `SharedPreferences` objects are intended to store small amounts of data anyway. If you need to store more data I would advise saving it to internal storage instead.

I have never had any problems storing and retrieving data to internal storage, whereas I run into bugs and irritating restrictions with `SharedPreferences` (such as no `putStringList`). For all but the simplest data I would avoid `SharedPreferences`.