# Shared prefrenences input error due to Gson

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

I get this IO exception every time i try to save object as json to shared preferences.

```
W/SharedPreferencesImpl: writeToFile: Got exception:
    java.io.IOException: java.nio.charset.CoderResult[Malformed-input error with erroneous input length 1]
    at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.flush(FastXmlSerializer.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.endDocument(FastXmlSerializer.java:198)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:193)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:600)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.-wrap2(SharedPreferencesImpl.java)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:515)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:536)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.-wrap0(SharedPreferencesImpl.java)
    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:458)
```

From log it seams that i give some bad string but i don't know what exactly is wrong.

my code that causes this is:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(value);

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPrefs(ctx);
prefs.edit().putString(key, json).commit();
```

Is there is any way of fixing this without writing some wild `ObjectOutputStream` ?

**Update**

My json that i trying to write looks like this when i print it to log:

```
 {"coordinates":{"latitude":54.55445,"longitude":25.54581,"mVersionCode":1},"name":"CityName"}
```

**Update 2**

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
```

This line is causing this in my given code this line is in `getSharedPrefs(context);` method. When i use `context.getSharedPreferences(set, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` everything somehow works fine.

Tho i notice that no matter what value i put to shared preferences i get this exception (from Default Shared Preferences).

In test app that i wrote, no errors occurs even if i try to save big json to 1000 different preferences.

App that thorws exception is way bigger and uses multidex.

Comment: you try and print in log what is inside json string BEFORE saving the data into shared preference. Check if json string contains valid/expected value.

Comment: I added my json. Not sure if  " should be changed with \" , but everything else looks valid.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to store the whole JSON as-is into shared pref. Ideally, you should parse and extract a specific field such as say version code in your json response and save that into shared pref. There are some known issues when storing this kind of response in shared pref. Here is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530733/android-sharedpreferences-ioexception-error

Comment: didn't help that link. But i will keep that your advice in mind. i solved it. I don't know why but it worked.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. :/   I want to save entire json, cause i need to store somewhere object that contains Weather  place setting.

Comment: According logcat you receive error from FastXmlSerializer, not from GSON.

Comment: AndreyICE, yes, i just use Gson as mechanism to create json and i don't say that something is wrong with that.